# Vertx how to timeout consumer if no message appears

Tags: java, vert.x

If a message doesn't appear after a timeout of `x` seconds I would like to throw an error. I can't find any built in way to do this. Any ideas?

This is my current code:

```
consumer = vertx.eventBus().consumer(correlationId);

consumer.handler(message -> {
    message.reply("Received");
    consumer.unregister();
});

consumer.exceptionHandler(exception -> {
    System.out.println("error");
    consumer.unregister();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use delayed task after creating your consumer.

```
vertx.setTimer(15000, l -> {
       System.out.println("error");
       consumer.unregister();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Took this route in the end:

```
  public Observable<String> consume(){
        return Observable.<String>create(s -> {

            messageConsumer = vertx.eventBus().consumer(channel);

            messageConsumer.handler(message -> {
                message.reply(messageReply);
                unregister();
                s.onNext(message.body());
                s.onComplete();
            });

            messageConsumer.exceptionHandler(this::error);

        })
        .timeout(timeoutMillis, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .doOnError(e -> {
            unregister();
        });
    }

  public void unregister(){
        if(messageConsumer != null) {
            messageConsumer.unregister();
        }
    }
```